# TypeError at /datatable datatable() missing 1 required positional argument: 'file'

Tags: python, django, web-development-server

In **views.py**

```
def datatable(request,file):
    csv_fp = open(f'csv_upload_files/{file}.csv', 'r')
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_fp)
    headers = [col for col in reader.fieldnames]
    out = [row for row in reader]
    return render(request, 'result.html', {'data' : out, 'headers' : headers})
```

In **urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.upload,name='upload'),
    path('datatable',views.datatable,name='datatable')
]
```

I am unable to understand how to provide the saved csv file to the function *datatable*

Comment: where does the file come from? Can you explain more about what you are trying to do and what is not going correct?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your url for `datatable`, since the view takes a `file` parameter you need to add it in the url.

that's why it is giving you error for argument file missing

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.upload,name='upload'),
    path('datatable/<str:file>',views.datatable,name='datatable')
]
```